# Is negative power always signifies a fraction if a number is in normalized scientific notation

Tags: irrational-numbers

Is my understanding correct that a number is in a scientific *normalized* form, a negative exponent always signifies a fraction? I'm thinking that if in a normalized form only one digit is allowed before the radix point, it's enough to have $-1$ in the exponent to have a fraction

Comment: Depends what you mean by "scientific normalized form", and what you mean by fraction. Are you using "fraction" just to mean any real number between zero and one?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, [scientific normalized form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_number). By fraction I mean any real number that is not an integer

Comment: Yes.  But you are badly abusing terminology and the word "fraction".  As you now scientific notation is $N=a.bc \times 10^k $.   If $k \ge 0$ then $10^k \ge 1$ and $N\ge 1$.  If $k <0$ then $10^k \le 1/10$ and $N <1$.  But *no* mathematician would call a number less than 1 a fraction, or a number greater than 1 a non-fraction.

Comment: A fraction is a fairly useless mathematical term.  It means anything written as a/b.  So 27/1 is a fraction but 27 is not.  1/4 is a fraction but .25 is not.  Anyway.... 7.345 x $10^2$ = 734.5 and has 3 leading terms.  w x $10^k;k \ge k $ will have k+1 leading terms.  7.345 x $10^{-3} $=0.007345$ which is.... OH!  I get what you meant!  You meant fraction*al* part!  Every real x = [x] + {x} where [x] is an integer and 0$\le $ {x} < 1.  {x} is called the fractional part.  It is true that if the exponent is negative, the number is "purely fractional" as the integer part is 0.

Comment: ....so 7.345 x 10^2 is a fraction?  Well, fine.  w x 10^-k = w/10^k < 1 is not an integer.  So you are correct.

Comment: @fleablood, I see, thanks a lot for your insights

Comment: Take what I say with a grain of salt as pure mathematicians seem to speak a different language than scientists.  But the upshot is.... what you thought a negative exponent meant is what a negative meant. (I.e.  less than 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so, we're talking about numbers of the form $\pm d_0.d_1d_2\dots\times10^n$ where the $d_i$ are digits, $d_0\ne0$, and $n<0$. Well, any such number is strictly between $-1$ and 1, and is not zero, so it's certainly not an integer.